# Show ellipsis in Tailwind CSS truncate

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am using the `truncate` property in Tailwind on a `p` tag, but it doesn't show the ellipsis after truncation. It only hides the overflow. Any idea how to show the 3 dots when it's truncated?

```
     <div className={containerClass}>
          <p className={nameClass}>{textName}</p>
          <p className='truncate'>{descriptionName}</p>
     </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow-hidden` to your container div?

Comment: SOLVED. i had to use display:block instead of flex for my container

Answer (score 0):

`className` is wrong attribute for HTML tags. You must use like this:

```
 <div class={containerClass}>
      <p class={nameClass}>{textName}</p>
      <p class='truncate'>{descriptionName}</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: i am writing in react